# Why is my code giving memory error?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, memory

I am making a program where I can count the number of `a` in a string. This is my Code:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    converged = s*n
    got_it = converged[0:n]
    count = 0
    for x in got_it:
        if "a" in x:
           count += 1
    return count
s = input()
n = int(input())
result = repeatedString(s, n)
print(result)
```

The variable `s` is where the string is entered, and variable `n` is for upto how long the string will repeat. My Code works OK, but for some reason when I give a bigger integer, it falls apart and gives  me a `Memory Error`. For example, my input is:

```
a
1000000000000
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "programs.py", line 11, in <module>
    result = repeatedString(s, n)
  File "programs.py", line 2, in repeatedString
    converged = s*n
MemoryError
```

How can I fix this Memory Error? If there's a better way to do it, it would also be helpful.

Comment: By getting terabytes of ram? Hard to fit a string of a trillion characters in memory otherwise.

Comment: Your code doesnt make sense, why do you only read `converged` up to ***n*** characters?

Comment: Even *assuming incorrectly* that Python 3 uses byte-strings (it doesn't), this would require `1000000000000*1e-9 == 1000 gigabytes`. Do you have a terabyte of memory?

Comment: To Everyone: No I don't have a terabyte of a memory

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, I managed to solve the problem by handling the exception using `try` and `except MemoryError`

Comment: The problem you have come through is from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/). Using `try-except` for this problem does not make you good at solving this problem. I apologize if this sound rude.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is where you do `converged = s*n`. In that line, you are asking the program to take the string `s` and allocate enough memory to fit the number of bytes in `s` * `n`, which, as you have seen, has a limit because your computer has a finite amount of free memory available (most modern-day computers only carry 4 - 16 gigabytes of RAM).

One way you can fix the memory error is by exploiting one aspect of your function - you are simply checking how many `"a"`'s fit in a string `s` repeated up to a length of `n`. So, instead of doing `converged = s*n` and subsequent modifications that require a lot of memory to store such a large string, you can instead use simple math to get the answer you are looking for.

Also, another optimization you could do is that you do not have to convert your string into an array to loop over it. Instead of doing `for x in got_it`, you could do `for c in s`.

Here is a working example of how you can accomplish what you need:

```
import math

def repeatedString(s, n):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0

    reps = float(n) / len(s)
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == "a":
           count += 1

    # After testing the code, it turns out that Python does not play nicely 
    # with rounding UP from 0.5, so this is necessary to get the correct answer
    result = count * reps

    if result - math.floor(result) < 0.5:
        return math.floor(result)

    return math.ceil(result)

s = input()
n = int(input())
result = repeatedString(s, n)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your code does solve the Memory Error but, it gives the wrong outputs. For example, if I  input string 'aba' and n = 10, it gives the output 20, but that's wrong because if aba is stretched abaabaabaa, with it's length 10, the output should be 7 because there are  7 occurrences of a in the string

Comment: @mahir I misunderstood what you meant by `n`. I've updated the code that I have to reflect what you have clarified for me, and I believe that it is correct now.

Comment: @mahir Please check the edit that I made to the rounding code.

Answer (score 0):

```
this program
  takes a input string named s
  repeats this string concatenated n times
  takes only the first n charactes in the concatenated
  counts how many times the letter "a" appears 


you
  you give the string "a"
  you give the number 1000000000000
  then the program should count and return 1000000000000


memmory problem
  I guess this string with 1000000000000 letters "a" is too big 
    for the type in the python language
    or for the computer memmory


the way it is
  given that the program searches for the fixed occurrences of letter "a"
  you passed exactly the letter "a" and the number 1000000000000
  the better way is that it's not necessary a program
  if you want to know how many times there is the letter "a" 
    in a string with 1000000000000 letters "a"
    the answer is obviously 1000000000000


extra:
  it would be complicated:
    to rewrite the program 
      to search for a pattern 
        given as input parameter, 
        with variable length
    AND
      avoid the memmory problem


  I guess I would write a program that 
    concatenates the "s" input just to have a length bigger than the searched pattern (if already not is)
    check if the pattern occurs

    after that multiply by "n"
    ajust the how many times it will 'fit' in the final
```

Answer (score 0):

one-line solution: find no of 'a' in string s, multiply with floor division of no.of repetition with the length of s +  finding 'a' in the remaining length of s

s.count("a") * (n // len(s)) + s[:n % len(s)].count("a")